# About the -ldl flag while compiling and linking C++ files

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, dynamic-linking

With reference to the following code

**test_linker.cpp**

```
int main() {

    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << rand() % 10 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**urandom.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <dlfcn.h>

int rand() throw() {

    // get the original rand() function
    static auto original_rand = (decltype(&rand)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"rand");

    cout << "Call made to rand()" << endl;
    return original_rand();
}
```

When I try to compile the code with the following command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wvla -pedantic -O3 urandom.cpp -c
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 test_linker.cpp urandom.o -ldl
```

everything works fine, but when I move the `-ldl` flag to being before the files, the linker throws an error saying

```
urandom.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

**Question 1** Could someone explain why this would happen?  I generally do not care about the order of flags in a compilation command.

**Question 2** Also is it wrong to keep the function pointer to the original `rand()` function a static variable? I do not know how exactly dynamic linking works and I am afraid that maybe the function address is moved around in memory at runtime.  The manual pages said that the `dlsym()` function with the `RTLD_NEXT` handle is an expensive computation so I just wanted to lazily evaluate this once.

Note : I am compiling this on a Linux distribution and the Linux dynamic linker is involved so I will go ahead and tag this with Linux also.

Comment: -ldl is not just a flag, it's a library designation, and the order of libraries and object files in the command line does matter.

Comment: Q2: no it's not wrong to kiip it in a static (as long as you're single-threaded). Addresses of functions don't change at run time.

Comment: Could you explain both your answers a bit more if you have time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`-ldl` is a library designation for the linker. It tells the linker to find and link a file named `libdl.so` (or sometimes `libdl.a`). It has the same effect as placing a full path to the library in question in the same position of the command line.

Library and object order on the command line does matter. Normally if library A calls library B, B should be placed after A on the command line. All libraries should normally go after all object files. This is covered extensively in several SO questions and answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc).

As for the second question, no, an address of a function doesn't change at run time unless you `dlopen` a shared library, then unload it, then `dlopen` it again. In your case, since you don't `dlopen` the library, it is safe to keep the function address in a static variable. Of course if you run multiple threads you need to ensure thread safety somehow (mutex it out, or use thread-local storage).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you explain why using dlopen would be bad in this case?

Comment: When you dlopen a library, you load all its function and data; when you unload it, all the functions and data cease to exist and are no longer accessible; when you dlopen it again, you are loading it to potentially different region of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Begin  with your  second  question, dynamic linking  works  during run time  either  way in  C/C++  we call  later  binding  with this -> operation. Of course  when  you are  invoking  later  binding declared  like an interface or class  instance,  should be pointing  to  the  specified  object  and  memory location  for  that  object.

The  first one question is more i think specific to  compiler.  I  guess  you  are  compiling not in  Visual Studio(Not in Windows  OS) if i am right  u should  ask  to the vendor  of the compiler  to  configure debugging  properties. :)

Comment: Oh  and  by the way about  your  Q2,  if  specified  function  is declared as volatile(but  this depends  compiler  properties and which compiler you  use) at  run time might be  that function  would  change  behavour  in memory  location :)