# What is the difference between shared and dynamic libraries in C?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I don't understand the difference between the two types of libraries, and many websites say that they are the same thing, but at school we use two different commands to create them

**dynamic library**

```
$ gcc -shared -o libsample.so lib.c
$ gcc -o main main.c -ldl
```

to execute:

```
$ ./main ./libsample.so
```

**shared library**

```
$ gcc -shared -o libsample.so lib.c
$ gcc -o main main.c -L. -lsample
```

to execute:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
```

Can someone help me in understanding the difference between the two "codes"?

Comment: Your libraries are created with the exact same command, and are exactly the same. The difference is in two versions of `main.c`. Perhaps you want to look at the code of `main.c` in order to understand it.

Comment: The difference between codes is the way the library are linked: In first case [-ldl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35324939/1212012)  suggest an explicit library loading, whereas on the second, the linking information are embedded in the program

Comment: I think you need to look for a difference between other two types of libraries, static and shared, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries

Answer (score 12):

*Dynamic* Linked Library (`.DLL`) is the terminology used by Microsoft Windows. *Shared* Object (`.so`) is the terminology used by Unix and Linux.

Other than that, conceptually they're the same.

Regarding your snippets of commands, I guess the difference (and I'm only guessing here, because you didn't show us the relevant parts) is how the library is loaded. There is *"link time loading"* where the library is tied to the executable by the linker¹. And there is *"runtime loading"*, where the program sort of "ingests" the dynamic/shared library.

runtime loading is done in Windows with the [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) (there's an `…A` and a `…W` variant) function, and on Unix/Linux with [`dlopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) (which is made available by `libdl` which is linked to by that `-ldl` library link statement).

---

1: The linker is the program that creates the actually executable file from the intermediary objects created by the various compiler stages.

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic and shared libraries are usually the same. But in your case, it looks as if you are doing something special.

- In the *shared library* case, you specify the shared library at compile-time. When the app is started, the operating system will load the shared library before the application starts.
- In the *dynamic libary* case, the library is not specified at compile-time, so it's not loaded by the operating system. Instead, your application will contain some code to load the library.

The first case is the normal case. The second case is a special use and it's mainly relevant if your application support extensions such a **plug-ins**. The dynamic loading is required because there can be many plug-ins and they are built after your application. So their names are not available at compile-time.